# Oracle PL/SQL Import Japanese values CSV file

Tags: oracle, unicode, csv, import, plsql

I am having problem with importing csv files containing values in japanese characters. When I do so it will display garbage when I query. my OS is japanese. My encoding for oracle NLS_LANG is JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJISTILDE. I don't know what the problem is. When I try to import the very same file in some of my office mates' PC it just works fine

Comment: What tool are you using to import the file?

Comment: What is your Oracle client NLS language setting? Is that different?

Comment: I am using Oracle PL/SQL. My Oracle NLS_LANG is JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJISTILDE

Comment: No. I am asking YOUR system client setup. Since it is working fine for others and not for you. The issue could be with your client NLS setting not the server.

Comment: yeah. I looked up in my registry and under KEY_OraClient11g_home1 NLS_LANG key has value JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJISTILDE.  Actually when I also tried to insert values or update through the SQL window in PL/SQL it saves garbage. But when I  right click the table->edit data and directly type the data it works fine

Comment: How do you read the file from PL/SQL? It could be using the wrong encoding when reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are on a windows client, spool the results of the sql into a flat-file and open the file in notepad.
do you see the Japanese characters ?

Regards,
--Amol

Answer (score -1):

You can try converting the database character set to UTF8 and see if that helps.

Comment: Not necessary, a lot of work, potential for characters that cannot be re-encoded.